# How does understanding of fragments differ from understanding of the whole?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, mathematical-logic

Consider a person reading a mathematical proof, then each syllogism from it's antecedent maybe understood by that person, yet they may find it difficult to understand the whole proof. At times however, a person maybe able to understand the proof as a whole, and in that case, provided they know the proper fundamental deductions, can deduce individual steps of the proof from it.

I hope the reader relates to this example I gave. In which case, I ask, why exactly is it difficult to move from understanding of the fragements to understanding of the whole? What is the missing piece?

Comment: People do not understand a proof by dissecting deductive steps of its formalization, at best, this only constitutes its verification. Semantic structures that are essential to human understanding of a proof, such as key ideas, their relation to known results and established techniques, etc.,  are often suppressed and obscured by formalization. See [SEP, Mathematical explanations within mathematics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-explanation/#MatExpWitMat).

Comment: What happens in maths is that there are many very precise definitions and prior theorems to keep in mind, so usually a good memory is required. And as Conifold says, sometimes some of those prior definitions and theorems may not be stated explicitly in a given proof, but assumed known by the reader, which compounds the effect.

Comment: I found it very difficult to answer this question in the context of mathematics. The physical analogy is "How does understanding atoms differ from understanding water?